# jQuery Tools 1.1.2, tabs plugin and History plugin

Tags: jquery, history

I have a question regarding the history plugin and jQuery Tools v. 1.1.2. I currently use the tabs plugin, and would very much like to have some kind of history-functionality. I need this so that I can link directly to one of my tabs.
I do only work with version 1.1.2 of jQuery Tools, because the 1.2.0 version conflicts with some of my other javascript. This means that I need to be able to link directly to my tabs with version 1.1.2 of Tools.

Right now my script looks like this:

```
$("ul.plan-tabs").tabs("div.plan-panes div.fane", { tabs: 'li'});
```

But I can't find any way to link directly to my tabs. Nomatter wich id(#) I puts in my URL, I always gets the first tab :(

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot in advance.

/Kim

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the history plugin for this to work:

```
$("ul.plan-tabs").tabs("div.plan-panes div.fane", { tabs: 'li', history: true });
```

[You can see it working in their demo here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/history.html).  For example, [here's a link directly to the third tab](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/history.html#streaming_tab).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in jQuery Tools (at least in version 1.2.5, probably in earlier versions, too) which prevents the history plugin (or, in fact, the entire tab functionality) from working if you’ve set the “tabs” option to anything, even if default. I’m yet waiting for a fix, have already mentioned it on their support forums.

So, currently the only working way to use the history plugin seems to be not to set `tabs: 'li'`.